# Get previous line number in stacktrace

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I am executing a method called MethodA, and inside that method, I want to get the line number of MethodA. I can get this number by

`var lineNumber = stacktrace.GetFrame(i).GetFileLineNumber()`

But, this only gets the line number of the next line that will execute after MethodA. This is problematic when I have a big space between MethodA and the next line of code.

Is there a way to get the previous line of the current line in stacktrace?

edit: 
MethodA is called in another file on line 100 by this

```
MethodA();
```

I want to find line 100

edit:

This error occurs in release mode but it is fine in debug mode

Edit:

So I figured out that i get the correct line number in when uncheck optimize code in build options. However this only works when I debug in release mode; when I just run in release mode, I get the wrong line number.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm going to guess there isn't a way, but I'm not certain.

Comment: When you say "MethodA" are you talking about the place where you call MethodA, the start of the MethodA method implementation, or some particular line within the MethodA implementation? It's not clear from your question. A simple code example would help.

Comment: It is an inevitable side effect of the way method calls work.  The address that's on the stack is the *return* address, where code should resume after the call completes.  Which is the machine code instruction *after* the CALL.  If that address is the start of the code generated by next statement in your source then the reported line number will be off by one.  There's no simple workaround for this.

Answer (score 2):

The previous line is the next frame in the stack.  The top of the stack is the current line, the next in line is the previous caller (which is the one you want).  A simple loop should grab the info you need:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        

        MethodA();//called from line 26 on my code

        

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MethodA()
    {
        var stacktrace = new StackTrace(true);//be sure to pass true to obtain line info


        for (int i = 0; i < stacktrace.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            var frame = stacktrace.GetFrame(i);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", frame.GetFileLineNumber(), frame.GetMethod(), frame.GetFileName(), frame.GetFileColumnNumber());
       
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUTS:**

> 35, Void MethodA(),
> c:\Development\General\Samples\WindowsFormsApplication1\Cons
> oleApplication1\Program.cs, 13
>
> 26, Void Main(System.String[]),
> c:\Development\General\Samples\WindowsFormsAppli
> cation1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs, 13

Note here the caller is on line **26**

Comment: I have the same code but I GetFileLineNumber gets the next line for me

Comment: @user2932876 - Strange.  Did you copy paste the example here?  Well, shot in the dark...are you running in debug mode or release?  If debug, maybe try compiling as x86 instead of any CPU.

Comment: oh yeah it works in debug mode, I need it in release mdoe though

Comment: @user2932876 - The information should come from the *.pdb files.  So my guess is somehow the pdb files are not being generated.  As of VS 2005 they should be generated with release mode by default.  What version of VS r u running?

Comment: I'm running 2012, my coworker told me to turn on pdb generation in release mode, trying it now